# Where's the right location for the file to load on .load(file) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load my b.html in the same folder as my main html but it won't load. I've copied the whole example from W3School and it doesn't do anything when I tes it manually by clicking my HTML file in my folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("b.html");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the `b.html` file is in the same folder as the current page this should work fine. Check the console for errors after making the AJAX request from the `load()` function. Also, please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. The jQuery documentation is far more comprehensive and accurate in this case: http://api.jquery.com/load

Comment: Also - make sure you're not running on your local file system, ie. `file://C:/folder/yourpage.html`. You cannot make AJAX requests under this protocol for obvious security reasons. You need to run on a webserver. You can easily install XAMP or IIS.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't use XAMPP before. Now it works. Got it now ^^